# Where to have parts of my thesis checked for correct English?

Tags: phrase-usage

I am now writing up my doctoral thesis. It is in theoretical physics so not very challenging as for language but still I would like to have corrected some parts like dedication, acknowledgement and the introduction by a native speaker. (Especially the dedication part needs some hints, as I wanted to be very original in it so I have to be sure that it sounds as I wanted it to sound:-) I know there are sites (though I forgot what) where people help each other on a reciprocal basis. **Recommendations?**

Note: I am not sure what tags this question should have, feel free to add some.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a request for resources

Comment: @FumbleFingers So in what forum does this question belong to? I think this is the most relevant one, as people learning English can have experience with it. I am asking what web-site would one suggest for this purpose, what is wrong with it?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the question per se, but this may not be the place to ask, that's all... If you participate in other ways on the website you might quickly earn enough reputation to ask for such advice in chat, perhaps :-)

Comment: @Lucky You wrote: "this may not be the place to ask, that's all...".  But I don't understand the reason why this is not the place to ask. What regulation of this forum am I violating? One cannot ask about other web-sites?

Comment: You might want to refer to the [help centre](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). As I have said this question would probably not be off topic in chat, but it is **off topic** on the main site as FumbleFingers has pointed out

Comment: @wondering: Read the [FAQ](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). You're specifically asked *not* to post **Proofreading** questions, or those which are **Requests for resources**.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Well, too bad, because I don't think there is a more suitable place to ask with such a high chance of getting a helpful answer but of course I want  to play according to rules so - shall I delete my question?